# Why undefined can be covered by with while null can't?

Tags: javascript, null, undefined

Why can `undefined` be covered by `with` while `null` can't?  And also, `let` can be covered while `var` can't (it will throw a error).

So what is the rule that a variable can be redefined?

[image]

```js
var obj = {null:1,undefined:2};
with(obj) console.log(null,undefined);
```

Comment: Please share your code here. Other wise we can not help you..

Answer (score 2):

Because `undefined` is a predefined global identifier, but [`null`](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-null-literals) is a literal. Because `var` is a [keyword](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-keywords), but `let` isn't (in loose mode; it is in [strict mode](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-strict-variant-of-ecmascript)). (In loose mode, it acts like a keyword or identifier depending on where it appears.)

I don't recall why `undefined` is a predefined global rather than being a keyword. The reason `let` is only a keyword in strict mode is that it was only added in 2015, 20 years after the language was first defined.

Comment: You can also override undefined (locally) which could lead to fun bugs: http://jsbin.com/sesisogico/edit?js,console

Comment: I'm surprised that `let` isn't a keyword. Apparently `var let = 1` is valid JavaScript. Was that done to preserve backward compatibility?

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫: Yes, although note that `let` is only allowed as an identifier in loose mode code; in strict mode code, `var let = 1` fails. New keywords are added only where it's unavoidable, ideally only contextually (`await` is only a keyword within an `async` function, for instance; `async` isn't a keyword at all; it just behaves like one if it's in the right place syntactically), and only after extensive research of code in the wild to determine the scope of the impact.